# Capture Paypal payment using curl php

Tags: php, curl, paypal, cakephp-2.3

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L/capture' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Paypal-Application-Correlation-Id: c2edbd6e97b14ff2b19ddb8eec9d264c" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer WfXdnxmyJtdF4q59ofxuQuAAk6eEV-Njm6puht3Nk3w" \
-d '{
   "amount":{
      "currency":"USD",
      "total":"1.50"
   },
   "is_final_capture":true
}'
```

I need this to be implemented using the `curl` functionality but I am getting no response on PHP.

I am doing this in such a way . but i am getting no response. I don't want to use sdk have to do this using curl .

```
     $data = array(
    "amount" => array(
        "currency" => "USD",
        "total" => $amount
    ),
    "is_final_capture" => "true"
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init( "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/$auth_id/capture" );        

curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token
```

//
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        )
    );

```
$result = curl_exec( $ch );  
var_dump($result); die;
```

Comment: u r doing it wrong, for the -d data, use CURLOPT_INFILE , to do a POST request, don't use CUSTOMREQEST, use CURLOPT_POST

Comment: idk what the downvotes are about though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, don't use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQEST for POST's, use CURLOPT_POST.
2nd, in your curl command line, you send a JSON to paypal, but in php, you're sending an invalid string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and... probably get undefined behavior (use http_build_query for POSTFIELDS, not json_encode). to send a json request body in PHP's curl, use CURLOPT_INFILE, like this:

```
<?php 
$postdata='{
   "amount":{
      "currency":"USD",
      "total":"1.50"
   },
   "is_final_capture":true
}';
$postdatafileh=tmpfile();
fwrite($postdatafileh,$postdata);
rewind($postdatafileh);
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_URL=>'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/$auth_id/capture',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Paypal-Application-Correlation-Id: foo',
'Authorization: Bearer barbaz',
'Content-Length: '.strlen($postdata)
),
CURLOPT_INFILE=>$postdatafileh,
CURLOPT_INFILESIZE=>strlen($postdata),
CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'',
CURLOPT_POST=>true
));

$ret=curl_exec($ch);
fclose($postdatafileh);
var_dump($ret,curl_errno($ch),curl_error($ch));
```